# React Router prevent route property update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I have a problem with react-router updating props everytime the component made route change.

In my document, I have multiple sections, and all sections are linked to navigation menu.. such as:

- /about#aboutus
- /about#contact

In the about component, I implemented a scrollSpy function like this:

```
scrollSpy() {
    if (this.isTransitioning) return;
    let hash = this.getCurrentSection();
    if (this.state.activeSection != hash) {
        this.setState({ activeSection: hash });
        history.pushState(null, null, hash);
    }
}
```

and also scrollTo function like this

```
scrollTo(hash) {
    this.isTransitioning = true;
    let section = $(hash);
    let body = $("html, body");
    let navBar = $("#mainNav");
    let top = section.offset().top - navBar.height() - 10;

    body.stop().animate({
        scrollTop: top
    }, 800, 'swing', () => {
        this.isTransitioning = false;
        this.scrollSpy();
    })
}
```

I also implement this function to scroll article to intended section when chosen from  at navigation bar.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.props.location.hash != prevProps.location.hash) {
        this.scrollTo(this.props.location.hash);
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is, when I insert a line to update history into scrollSpy like this:

```
scrollSpy() {
    if (this.isTransitioning) return;
    let hash = this.getCurrentSection();
    if (this.state.activeSection != hash) {
        this.setState({ activeSection: hash });
        history.pushState(null, null, hash);
        this.props.history.push(hash);
    }
}
```

System would scroll indefinitely, up and down.

It seems the component send signal to React-Router, and react-router change props, and scrollSpy again send back to react-router. So it kind of stuck in a loop. Adding a variable such as `isUpdating = true` didn't help, and made its behavior unpredictable. Sometimes it will scroll, sometimes it just won't, sometimes it jumped back to top.

How can I determine whether props change comes from my history.push trigger or a user clicking navigation bar? I want the page to scroll to desired top of section when user clicks on the navigation bar, even when it is the current section shown on screen.

Thank you